# node-fetch returned undefined values

Tags: node.js, node-fetch

I'm trying to write a code about GTFS with node-fetch. When I use the promise, It can return values but when I try to add them into an array for information filtering purposes. The system returned undefined values. What can I do with this situation?

```
function getStopInfo(StopId){

        mta.schedule(StopId).then(function (result) {
                console.dir(result, {depth:null, colors:true});});
}

global.info = getStopInfo('627');    
global.a = Array(20).fill(info);    
console.log(global.a);
```

Here are the return values:

```
[ undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined ]
```

Comment: IN addition, I have the value returned from the function by when I try to access the array of objects. The system said the value 'info' is undefined.

Comment: Here are the result of function.

Comment: { schedule: 
   { '627': 
      { N: 
         [ 
           { routeId: '6',
             delay: null,
             arrivalTime: 1533738510,
             departureTime: 1533738510 } ],
        S: 
         [ 
           { routeId: '6',
             delay: null,
             arrivalTime: 1533739230,
             departureTime: 1533739230 } ] } },
  updatedOn: 1533735302 }